# What is the difference between isdigit() and isnumber()?

Tags: c++, string, ctype

I have the function isnumber() in my ctype.h. I don’t find references of this function in the books I have neither in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/ for consult. 
I intend to detect and show the difference between isdigit() and isnumber() by a simple  example, but there is not (besides, U+0C6A, U+0ED2 and ½ are undetectable by the functions). 
Is there any difference? How could I resolve that?

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
    string text("Hello½123, Poly౪ ໒girl0.5!!!");
    decltype(text.size()) punct = 0, alpha = 0, number = 0, space = 0, digit = 0, graf = 0;
    for(auto i : text) {
        if(ispunct(i)){
            cout << i << "<punct  ";
            ++punct;
        }
        if(isalpha(i)) {
            cout << i << "<alpha  ";
            ++alpha;
        }
        if(isnumber(i)) {
            cout << i << "<number  ";
            ++number;
        }
        if(isdigit(i)) {
            cout << i << "<digit  ";
            ++digit;
        }
        if(isgraph(i)) {
            cout << i << "<graph  ";
            ++graf;
        }
        if(isspace(i))
            ++space;
    }
    cout << endl << "There is " << endl;
    cout << punct <<  " puncts," << endl;
    cout << alpha << " alphas," << endl;
    cout << number << " numbers," << endl;
    cout << digit << " digits," << endl;
    cout << graf << " graphs," << endl;
    cout << space << " spaces" << endl;
    cout << "in " << text << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A part of the result:

```
...

5 numbers,
5 digits,
23 graphs,
2 spaces
in Hello½123, Poly౪ ໒girl0.5!!!
```

Comment: Which compiler is that, and on what kind of machine?

Answer (score 6):

`isnumber()` may be an Apple-specific C++ method (I don't have a Mac on hand to check).
You can see it in the [Apple dev guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/isnumber.3.html):

> The `isnumber()` function behaves similarly to `isdigit()`, but may recognize additional characters, depending on the current locale setting.

---

Besides, `isnumber()` is not declared on Linux:
I use g++ 6.1.1 on Linux 4.7.2 and get the error:

```
g++ a.cpp
a.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
a.cpp:20:17: error: 'isnumber' was not declared in this scope
   if (isnumber(i)) {
                 ^
```

I also use clang3.8.1 to test:

```
clang++ a.cpp --std=c++11
a.cpp:20:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'isnumber'
                if (isnumber(i)) {
                    ^
```

Comment: The compiler is Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31). Look at my coment @ songyuanyao

Answer (score 4):

`isdigit()` only works with 0-9.

`isnumber()` allows other number values such as fractions. Some characters that are 'numeric' but not digits include 0x00b2 and 0x00b3 which are superscripted 2 and 3 ('²' and '³') and the glyphs that are fractions such as '¼', '½', and '¾'.

Comment: @songyuanyao __DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline int
isnumber(int _c)
{
 return (__istype(_c, _CTYPE_D)); 
}     of ctype.h

Comment: @Isi It seems to be a non-standard function, might be provided by implementation or platform. I just want to who provide it, or the source of the quoted information.

Comment: @songyuanyao I will repeat: it is my ctype.h.

Comment: @lsi: You can "repeat" as many times as you like but you're not understanding what is being asked

Answer (score 2):

The `isnumber()` function was added by Apple, so you need to use Apple documentation.

Here's a quote from [the `ctype.h` manpage for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/ctype.3.html)<sup>†</sup>:

> ```
> STANDARDS
>      These functions, except for digittoint(), isascii(), ishexnumber(),
>      isideogram(), isnumber(), isphonogram(), isrune(), isspecial() and
>      toascii(), conform to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (``ISO C90'').
> ```

The same page doesn't actually link to a manpage for `isnumber()`, but I extrapolated its URL from the links to manpages for the standard functions, and found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/isnumber.3.html):

> ```
> The isnumber() function behaves similarly to isdigit(), but may recognize
> additional characters, depending on the current locale setting.
> ```

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Result #4 on Google for `isnumber ctype`…</sup>